# solution: ts file defined in parent/parallel folder to give import in child module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have defined directive inside app folder since it is common directive and trying to use in child module project which is inside app/dashboard/project
folder so when I am trying to import it in my child module it is giving can not file module error. same happened when I try to use any service defined in top module and to import in child module.

```
import { CpLoopDecorator }  from '../app.facets.directive';
[ts] Cannot find module '../app.facets.directive'.
```

solution: 
It is just issue with relative path so once I did ../../app.facets.directive it started giving reference of file since I was importing it in child module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the relative path to the file `'../app.facets.directive'` and check that the file name is correct.

Answer (score 1):

i think you didn't export it, please export your directive in your module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    facetsDirective
  ],

  exports: [facetsDirective]<== add this line
})
```

Comment: I have done with exports: [CpLoopDecorator] in my app.module.ts but still same result I have folder structure like app module then its child is dashboard module and then dashboard child is project module and in project component I have project.html and there I have to use my directive. it is saying Property binding cpLoop not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("<ul>
i have not defined directive template

Comment: when I put code in app.component.html it works so now I need to see how your directive defined in app.module can be used in childs module

Comment: i have tried to created shared module in which I have defined directive but when i am trying to access it in my child module project it is giving same error ERROR in src/app/dashboard/projects/projects.module.ts(9,34): error TS2307: Cann
ot find module './shared/app.facets.directive'.

Comment: got it by import { SharedModule }  from '../../shared/app.shared.module'; since i am trying to import inside child of parallel folder

Comment: and did you add the directive in the exports?

Comment: import { CpLoopDecorator } from './app.facets.directive';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CpLoopDecorator
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [CpLoopDecorator]
})

export class SharedModule { } and i have import this in my project module but still not able to display in project.html

Comment: import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA }             from '@angular/core';

import { SharedModule }  from '../../shared/app.shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ProjectsRoutingModule,BrowserModule,FormsModule,SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProjectsComponent
    
  ],
  providers: [
    ProjectsService,
    DatePipe
  ],schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
]
})
export class ProjectsModule {}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158871/discussion-between-rahul-kumar-jain-and-fateh-mohamed).

Comment: again stuck at iterating array on my html however it is able to console inside directive ts file. cant i get a simple example on google where any array has been printed html template using ngFor attribute

Comment: in html i am getting this <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-loop": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->